# How to match text string in a cell approximately

Tags: excel

I've got this formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('[Fishing Contact list July 2015.xlsm]Places'!$A$2:$A$65, SMALL(INDEX(ROW($1:$64)+('[Fishing Contact list July 2015.xlsm]Places'!$Q$2:$Q$65="A"&'[Fishing Contact list July 2015.xlsm]Places'!$B$2:$B$65>="Fishing")*1E+99, , ), ROW(1:1))),"No Active Fishing Places")
```

which is designed to look in another workbook in column B for the word " Fishing" and return the names of the fishing places which are written in column A only if in column Q an A has been written and in column B the text matches the word Fishing.

The problem I am having is that in column B there is not just the text Fishing. There is often, "Fishing/Lakes" or "Fishing/SaltWater" for example. I need a way of just using the word "Fishing" to find a match (as well as using A in column Q) without having to individually write out the words.

At the moment it just returns "No Active Fishing Places". If I reverse the >="Fishing" to <="Fishing" the value returned is 0.

I have also tried fitting match into the formula which should have allowed me to use "Fishing*" but this did not seem to work either).

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have also tried

`=IFERROR(INDEX('[Fishing Contact list July 2015.xlsm]Places'!$A$2:$A$65, SMALL(INDEX(ROW($1:$64)+MATCH("A",'[FishingContact list July 2015.xlsm]Places'!$Q$2:$Q$65,0),MATCH("Fishing*",'[Fishing Contact list July 2015.xlsm]Places'!$B$2:$B$65,1)*1E+99, , ), ROW(1:1))),"No Active Fishing Places")`

but it was to no avail, it simply returned the error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In place of a potentially resource-heavy `IFERROR` set-up, it's preferable to reference a single helper cell which counts the number of expected returns. See here for an explanation if interested:

https://superuser.com/questions/812727/look-up-a-value-in-a-list-and-return-all-multiple-corresponding-values/812848#812848

For example, if you use E1 for this purpose, then we would enter this formula in that cell:

`=COUNTIFS('[Fishing Contact list July 2015.xlsm]Places'!$B$2:$B$65,"* Fishing *",'[Fishing Contact list July 2015.xlsm]Places'!$Q$2:$Q$65,"A")`

*Edit*: I had to put spaces after the first and before the second asterisk in "* Fishing *", as the editor would not allow it otherwise. Please remove these two spaces when you paste the formula into Excel.

Your main array formula is then:

`=IF(ROWS($1:1)>$E$1,"No Active Fishing Places",INDEX('[Fishing Contact list July 2015.xlsm]Places'!$A:$A,SMALL(IF('[Fishing Contact list July 2015.xlsm]Places'!$Q$2:$Q$65="A",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Fishing",'[Fishing Contact list July 2015.xlsm]Places'!$B$2:$B$65)),ROW('[Fishing Contact list July 2015.xlsm]Places'!$B$2:$B$65))),ROWS($1:1))))`

and copied down until you start to get blanks.

Also note that `ROWS` is a more rigorous choice than `ROW` for generating `SMALL`'s *k* parameter:

http://excelxor.com/2014/08/25/row-vs-rows-for-consecutive-integer-generation/

Regards

Comment: Your solution is perfect although I am having a slight problem. The function for finding the number of volunteers with A in the Q column and Fishing in the B column is perfect and works correctly. However I cannot seem to get it to show the names of the places that have met the criteria. 

What happens is it displays the names of all the places which do not meet both criteria and then displays a 0 for all the names that do.

Comment: In addition it will not display all of the names only the first one (even after dragging down), then Num# then No Active Fishing Places!.

So for example.

`Sea                                                                
#NUM!                                                                     
No Active Fishing Places!                                                               
No Active Fishing Places!                                                            
No Active Fishing Places!`

Comment: That formula cannot display #NUM!, since, by referencing the value in cell E1, it ensures that, in rows beyond the expected number of returns, a blank will be returned. Are you sure you haven't amended the formula I posted in some way?

Comment: I haven't altered it at all.

Comment: What is the current value being returned in cell E1?

Comment: 2. I've checked and there are two rows where in column Q there is the value A and in column B there is the value Fishing.

Comment: And what are the results of the first three instances of the main formula?

Comment: Also if I copy the formula in the first cell it displays the first name in the workbook i am getting the information from. If i copy it in the second cell it displays the second name , when it reaches a name that matches the criteria it displays 0. I don't really understand why its doing this and why when I drag down it displays the first name in the workbook when it should only display the names that match the criteria.

Comment: In response to your question above its. Sea #NUM! No active Fishing Places!

Comment: I don't understand how your last two comments are consistent. Either you are getting "Sea", #NUM!, "No Active Fishing Places", or you are getting, as you say, the first name, followed by the second name, etc., etc. But it can't be both of those results simultaneously.

Comment: Dont worry I just figured out my stupid, stupid, stupid, stupid mistake. I didn't press Ctrl,Shift,Enter. The formula now works perfectly thankyou.

Comment: Ah! Ok! You're welcome. BTW please see my (crucial) edit to the first formula which was originally hampered by the post editor here.